Threading plumbing certain orientation
It doesn’t matter how many times or which ways I try putting this plumbing together to thread it keeps landing in the same spot, and I need it to be orientated 45° angle. I’d like to know what tricks or whatever to get it to fit right.

A few (or more) wraps of thread tape can change the point at which it gets 'tight enough'.

There usually is a range(about a half turn) where the fitting will not leak.  About half way between too loose and too tight.

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/190844/18078

And if you really need a specific orientation there are unions that you can use. Although that does add another joint.
